# How do I make a font similar to the Segoe UI Emoji font?

Tags: fonts, emoji, windows-11, glyph-substitution

So I'm wondering if it's possibile to make a sepreate font for Emojis/Glyphs. The type I need is the Segoe UI Emoji font in Windows 10/11. Is there any way to make a font with full-colored emojis/glyphs?

I was trying to implement custom glyphs into my terminal project (the full colored ones, cause they just look nice.)

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

- [FontCreator](https://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator)
- [FontLab](https://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab/)
- [nanoemoji](https://github.com/googlefonts/nanoemoji) & [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools)

Comment: Alright, I'll try it.

Comment: The font is taken care of, but I'm still wondering something else. If you use Windows 11 and put Emojis in your batch files. Not only do they render in full color and anything, they are also compatibile with a normal font (Consolas for Example) How would I do that in batch

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Alright I'll make it clear. I want to use both my emoji font and another font (eg. Consolas) in the batch program (or C# program). How do I do that? I know this is possible cause in Windows when you put emojis in your batch project you can do that without having to do nerd font stuff? That's the result i needd